# loading k:v pairs from DB into JS Object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm creating a single player web RPG.

I'm debating the following method of storing/retrieving quest items per player id:

- In `userstats` table, have a `quest_items` column of type `mediumtext`, where I would store the total amount of the item the player has as key, and item_name as value, like so:

[image]

If I were to do it this way, how can I load that column data JSON into a JS object, where the key : value pairs are maintained, like so loaded for player "DAN":

```
quest_items = { 2 : "rice", 1 : "meat" };
```

---

- Or, the alternative is to have some sort of association table, where I store the user_id against the item_id, maintaining single data in each column:

[image]

The issue with this is, each time a user gained a quest item, I would have to update this table, which could be costly.

---

Preferably, I would like to go with option 1, and

- when I need to update the quest_items in `userstats`, I simply pass in a js object with new data, JSON_encode it, and save it into the DB column as text.
- when I need to read it back out, just JSON_decode it

Is it bad to store k:v pairs this way in a DB field?

Comment: You typically would use an entity relationship, superficially one to many to accomplish this.

Comment: It would be a mistake to use the quantity of an item as the key; it wouldn't be a unique value.  It would also be a mistake to worry about the cost of a database update at the frequency of finding quest items.  Databases are built to update thousands, or millions, of rows in seconds.  Don't optimize or architect for imaginary database bottlenecks.